# Python time-series, get back original after making two differences

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a lengthy time series data. But let's just use a minimal example here, with 10 random numbers as my time series dataset.

```
In [60]: from numpy.random import RandomState                                   

In [61]: prng = RandomState(32)                                                 

In [62]: series = pd.Series(prng.random(10))                                    

In [63]: series                                                                 
Out[63]: 
0    0.858889
1    0.372711
2    0.555129
3    0.955657
4    0.736670
5    0.816205
6    0.101087
7    0.928488
8    0.609109
9    0.596553
dtype: float64
```

Let's assume that the above is my time series dataset and is not stationary.
To make it stationary, I am doing the following:

```
In [64]: series['diff'] = series.diff().diff()                                                   
Out[64]: 
0         NaN
1         NaN
2    0.668596
3    0.218110
4   -0.619515
5    0.298522
6   -0.794654
7    1.542520
8   -1.146780
9    0.306823
dtype: float64
```

Now, I apply the `ARIMA` model to predict:

```
arima_model = ARIMA(series['diff'],order=(1,0,0) 
results_arima = arima_model.fit(disp=-2)
prediction = results_arima.fittedvalues
```

Now, `prediction` will only have 8 values, as we have done two differences. **How do I get the `prediction` array to be in the same scale as my original `series`?**
i.e. The `prediction` array will not be in the same "scale" as my original `series` and will also be missing the first two values.

Comment: Can you show the expected output ?

Comment: The `prediction` array is not in the same scale as my original series and is also missing two values. I want to get it back to the same scale as my original series and also get back the first two missing points.

Comment: After two diff the first two value will become NaN , what would you like them to be ?

Comment: you could align the prediction with `series.loc[2:, 'pred'] = prediction`

Comment: having no prediction for the first values is just a result of the transformation you applied, there is no way around it (i.e. you cannot get a prediction if `series['diff'] == NaN`)

Comment: @BEN_YO: but the `prediction` has a scale in terms of the "detrended" series. I want to get it back to the original scale. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Check with `reindex`

```
news = pd.Series(prediction, index=series.index[series.notna()]).reindex(series.index)
```